# What is the WSS Certificate Web Service?

Tags: essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

What is the WSS Certificate Web Service?

I found that on Windows Server 2012 Essentials it was installed automagically. I've stopped the site for now, but would like to know why its there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "WSS" stands for ["Windows Server Solutions," which is the platform name for the Small Business/Essentials versions of Windows server](https://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/04/08/introducing-the-windows-server-solutions-bpa.aspx).  So, "WSS Certificate Web Service" would be "Windows Server Solutions Certificate Web Service."

So, it's a web server that serves certificates for the Windows Server Solutions platform.

[This service is used to allow certificate-based authentication for remote connections to the server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/computer-connection-support-2.aspx#BKMK_ServiceStopped) that require certificate-based authentication.  It's a web service because [Microsoft made a design decision in this line of products to expose their APIs over a web service where possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713755.aspx), presumably in the interests of making them easier to work with, which would make sense given the target market of this product line.